# Moving failed files to different directory

Tags: java

I am trying to move failed files to different directory(not copying, but moving).

```
 originalfilename.renameTo(new File("C"));
```

It's giving me that renameTo is undefined for type String. Why am I getting this? Is there any other simpler API or statements to acheive this?

EDIT:How to move to different directory rather than creating a new file?

Comment: Is this Java 6 or Java 7?

Answer (score 1):

`renameTo` is a method of the `File` class, you are trying to use it on a `String`.

```
File original = new File(originalfilename);
original.renameTo(new File("C"));
```

Comment: how do I make it a directory instead of "file"? When I do this, it's making a new file instead of a folder.

Comment: @user2482974 if this is Java 7, drop `File`; see the `Files` class, it has all you want